# How must a json look to force mongodb to BinData subtype 4

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using the c# driver MongoDB.Driver 2.16.0
I'm trying to insert pure json.
I want the _id to be used as the new UUID type aka BinData subtype 4. But I get only subtype 3 or pure string.

```
var testColl = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("test");
var testJson = "[{'_id':CSUUID('609e26f6-dbad-4dba-ba37-4e35f0e348ec'),'name':'Data1'},{'_id':CSUUID('609e26f6-dbad-4dba-ba37-4e35f0e348ff'),'name':'Data2'}]";
testColl.InsertMany(BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument[]>(testJson));
```

I tried '_id':'609e26f6-dbad-4dba-ba37-4e35f0e348ec' which results in a string.
I tried '_id':UUID('609e26f6-dbad-4dba-ba37-4e35f0e348ec') which rusults in subtype 3.
And the example code also results in subtype 3.

How must the json look to make a subtype 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following options:

1. Configure `BsonDefaults.GuidRepresentationMode = GuidRepresentationMode.V3;`. In this case, you will work with subTypes specified in the document (or via attributes see the doc in the end). If it's `CSUUID` - then subType is 3, `UUID` - 4.
2. Configure `GuidSerialization.Unspecified`. For example during collection creating:

   ```
   db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(
       "coll", 
       new MongoCollectionSettings() { GuidRepresentation = GuidRepresentation.Unspecified});
   ```

this case is similar to #1 where we get used subType from a document, but only for a particular collection

3. Configuring `GuidSerialization.Standard` to force using this particular `subType` for a collection regardless a `subType` provided in the document:

   ```
   var coll = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("coll", new MongoCollectionSettings() { GuidRepresentation = GuidRepresentation.Standard});
   var testJson = "[{'_id':CSUUID('609e26f6-dbad-4dba-ba37-4e35f0e348ec'),'name':'Data1'},{'_id':CSUUID('609e26f6-dbad-4dba-ba37-4e35f0e348ff'),'name':'Data2'}]";
   coll.InsertMany(BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument[]>(testJson)); // inserted subType is 4 (UUID/Standard)
   ```

You also can configure GuidRepresentation globally like: `BsonDefaults.GuidRepresentation = GuidRepresentation.Standard;`. In this case you will force using this representation by default everywhere (for GuidRepresentationMode.V2 which is default mode)

You can find details [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.16/reference/bson/guidserialization/guidrepresentationmode/guidrepresentationmode/)

Comment: thank you for the answer. But BsonDefaults.GuidRepresentationMode is marked as obsolete. What is the "new" way?

Comment: #2 and #3 ways are "old" and obsoleted, but also default for now, #1 is a new and expected. `BsonDefaults.GuidRepresentationMode = GuidRepresentationMode.V3` is also marked as obsoleted, but AFAIK it's made in this way to be able to fully remove all this configuration in next major driver release and leave only `V3` approach without any mentions about existence V2/V3